# Checking if a cookie exists via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

Excerpt from the manifest:

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "*://*/*"
   ]
```

The code I tried on Popup.js (didn't work):

```
function getCookie(name) {
var dc = document.cookie;
var prefix = name + "=";
var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
}
else
{
    begin += 2;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
    end = dc.length;
    }
}
return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 


function doSomething() {
var myCookie = getCookie("TestCookie");

if (myCookie == null) {
document.write("<p>unable to load</p>");
throw "stop execution";
}
else {
document.write("<p>loaded</p>");
    // do cookie exists stuff
}
}
```

I gather that chrome extension doesn't support full blown java, though I'm not sure. How could I approach this situation?

Comment: If you want to read cookies from extension, you should use chrome.cookies.get or [chrome.cookies.getAll](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html#method-getAll) methods. There is an example at Chrome's site - [Cookie API Test extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#2b0f7d02f3ebd51358ed54ef59dceebb).

Comment: Thanks Stan, but that's not very helpful, at all. It's like saying there's a needle in the haystack without saying which region it's at. I've seen that, but I haven't figured out how to work it towards my goal.

Comment: If you saw this, why did not you use this in your code at all? The cookies API is very simple and minimal. Any answer, if it appears, will somehow require you to follow existing examples.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear what cookies do you want to get. If you set cookie inside your extension you can access it by `document.cookie` but it is not the right way for saving persistent info in extension because there are better things like `localStorage` or `chrome.storage`. But if you need to get site cookies in extension the best way is like this:

```
chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'http://example.com', name: 'somename' },
  function (cookie) {
    if (cookie) {
      console.log(cookie.value);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Can\'t get cookie! Check the name!');
    }
});
```

Don't forget to include permissions into manifest:

```
"permissions": [
  "cookies",
  "*://*.example.com/*"
]
```